# How to replicate (fork) the current terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal, productivity

Say I am using terminal and have `ssh`ed to a remote machine and did something.
How do I create a new terminal tab (or window) so I still has everything from the previous terminal window without having to do the whole thing like `ssh`, `cd`, etc. – just like forking. Then I can start working in the new window separately from the previous one.

Comment: Is an X11 window sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask, because you don't have a new real window or tab.

You can start [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) on the server (if available), so that you can multiplex your server sessions.

After that you have still a single `screen` window, but if you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>, you create a new `screen` window, and switch between the windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>.

You have the added advantage that you can disconnect from the server leaving the two (or more) sessions alive (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>), then restore them later (`screen -dr`).

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. gnome-terminals however could preserve the current working directory if invoked from the terminal's right-click menu. But asking it to ssh would be difficult perhaps thing to do in a straight away fashion. However, there is this gnome specific panel applet (I guess written in ruby) that can help you manage your ssh connections in a menu based interaction. http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution: use `screen` or `tmux`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I like to do here is ssh X redirection. You do **NOT** need X installed on the remote machine to do this.

I use a small wrapper script called [xon](http://cvsweb.openbsd.mirror.frontiernet.net/X11/xc/programs/scripts/xon.sh?rev=1.2&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&hideattic=0), but you could use a simple `ssh -Y -f hostname.tld xterm`

Now at some point I want to open a new terminal, I can just type `xterm` again, and I will have a new xterm from the remote server.

Server requirements: xterm, xauth